# Clickhouse - query performance degradation

Tags: clickhouse

I have a simple query that runs quite fast (1-2 seconds) and returns 20 rows:

```
select * from table where field1 = 'ABC'
```

However, if I add one more filter on another field, like:

```
select * from table where field1 = 'ABC' and field2 = 'XYZ'
```

the query times out (we have a limit of 30 secs). If it matters, the query is expected to return the same 20 rows in our case.

Both fields are not part of the sort key, and the table contains about 250 million rows with about 20 columns.

The question is: is it expected behaviour? I would expect the queries run times should be more or less equal. If it is expected, is there a guide what kind of queries one should avoid, or is there a tool that allows to investigate whether it's a "bad" query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is natural to second query to take longer since there will be more comparision but I can't figure out how it takes more than 30 seconds. What do you mean by time out? Are you sending query from `clickhouse-client` or JDBC?

Comment: Could you reveal the types of both columns? I suspect that *select * from table where field2 = 'XYZ'* takes a long time too - could you check it?

Comment: you can try this one: select * from (select * from table where field1 = 'ABC') where field2 = 'XYZ' settings enable_optimize_predicate_expression=0;

Comment: Thanks guys! 1) Just via REST 2) Yes, it does. 3) Works fast. I guess Denis elaborated already and all seems clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's expected. In some cases CH chooses a wrong column for prewhere because it  has no statistics and uses rule-based algorithm.

Try

```
select * from table 
prewhere field1 = 'ABC' 
where field2 = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: Your answers are always great, I need to collect all these and make a "best clickhouse tips".

Comment: Thanks, Denis! Things are bit clearer now. But I thought it any case the full table scan occurs where most of the rows are filtered out. Why does it make a difference. Also you mentioned a rule-based algorithm. If CH does not have stats, what are other variables are taken into account then?

Comment: @Vyacheslav CH uses some columns (lightweight - small) to do prewhere (first filtering). So CH reads `prewhere field1 = 'ABC' ` field1 column using PrimaryKey filters (not in this case) and collects suitable marks (pointers to granulas which  = 'ABC' ). On the second stage CH reads all other columns (* in this case) using that collected marks and filters = 'XYZ'. In case of optimize_move_to_prewhere the algorithm chooses the smallest (in bytes) column -- for example field2 the problem that this condition field2 = 'XYZ' could be true for all rows and CH filters out nothing on the PREWHERE stage

Comment: BTW, it could be that `prewhere field1 = 'ABC' and field2 = 'XYZ'` will be even better

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!